# How to keep last web session active in react-native-webview?

Tags: react-native, authentication, session, cookies, react-native-webview

I am working on one app, In which I need to keep users last web-session active in `react-native-webview`.

**Here is a required work-flow.**

- My app is only have one WebView, Where there is fixed url is loading.
- User will open app & login to that website.
- When user will kill app & open it again, I need to keep that user logged in as he has already logged in last time.

**Here is what i tried so far:**

- I did try with https://github.com/react-native-community/cookies. Till now I am only able to save cookies via below function :

// list cookies (IOS ONLY)

```
CookieManager.getAll(useWebKit)
    .then((res) => {
        console.log('CookieManager.getAll from webkit-view =>', res);
    });
```

But as it's suggested, It'll only work in iOS. I am also not able to set that cookies in website that is opened in WebView to keep that session active.

- Also used this one, https://gist.github.com/kanzitelli/e5d198e96f81b7a8263745043766127c

But I didn't found any success yet.

Any suggestion or solution will highly appreciated.

**======= Update =======**

For Android:

It is working by default,
That means we only need to check this for iOS.

Comment: from my experience, this seems relevant only to session cookies (which don't have an expiry date in the future).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

actually this problem exist in react-native-webview

[Cookies are lost on iOS after application closing](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-webview/issues/528)

it should be resolve through native code. but today I made a solution and tested with PHP website

### Full Code

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {StyleSheet, SafeAreaView} from 'react-native';
import {WebView} from 'react-native-webview';
import CookieManager from '@react-native-community/cookies';
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-community/async-storage';

let domain="http://example.com";

export default class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.currentUrl = '';
    this.myWebView = React.createRef();
    this.state = {
      isReady: false,
      cookiesString: '',
    };
  }

  jsonCookiesToCookieString = (json) => {
    let cookiesString = '';
    for (let [key, value] of Object.entries(json)) {
      cookiesString += `${key}=${value.value}; `;
    }
    return cookiesString;
  };

  componentWillMount() {
    this.provideMeSavedCookies()
      .then(async (savedCookies) => {
        let cookiesString = this.jsonCookiesToCookieString(savedCookies);
        const PHPSESSID = await AsyncStorage.getItem('PHPSESSID');
        if (PHPSESSID) {
          cookiesString += `PHPSESSID=${PHPSESSID};`;
        }
        this.setState({cookiesString, isReady: true});
      })
      .catch((e) => {
        this.setState({isReady: true});
      });
  }

  onLoadEnd = (syntheticEvent) => {
    let successUrl = `${domain}/report.php`;
    if (this.currentUrl === successUrl) {
      CookieManager.getAll(true).then((res) => {
        AsyncStorage.setItem('savedCookies', JSON.stringify(res));
        if (res.PHPSESSID) {
          AsyncStorage.setItem('PHPSESSID', res.PHPSESSID.value);
        }
      });
    }
  };
  onNavigationStateChange = (navState) => {
    this.currentUrl = navState.url;
  };


  provideMeSavedCookies = async () => {
    try {
      let value = await AsyncStorage.getItem('savedCookies');
      if (value !== null) {
        return Promise.resolve(JSON.parse(value));
      }
    } catch (error) {
      return {}
    }
  };

  render() {
    const {cookiesString, isReady} = this.state;
    if (!isReady) {
      return null;
    }
    return (
      <SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
        <WebView
          ref={this.myWebView}
          source={{
            uri: `${domain}`,
            headers: {
              Cookie: cookiesString,
            },
          }}
          scalesPageToFit
          useWebKit
          onLoadEnd={this.onLoadEnd}
          onNavigationStateChange={this.onNavigationStateChange}
          sharedCookiesEnabled
          javaScriptEnabled={true}
          domStorageEnabled={true}
          style={styles.WebViewStyle}
        />
      </SafeAreaView>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#FFF',
  },
  WebViewStyle: {
    flex: 1,
    resizeMode: 'cover',
  },
});
```

### Detail:

**Step 1:**

get [cookies](https://github.com/react-native-community/cookies) after login and save in [AsyncStorage](https://github.com/react-native-community/async-storage) like this

```
onNavigationStateChange = (navState) => {
    this.currentUrl = navState.url;
  };
```

```
 onLoadEnd = () => {
    let successUrl = `${domain}/report.php`;
    if (this.currentUrl === successUrl) {
      CookieManager.getAll(true).then((res) => {
        AsyncStorage.setItem('savedCookies', JSON.stringify(res));
        if (res.PHPSESSID) {
          AsyncStorage.setItem('PHPSESSID', res.PHPSESSID.value);
        }
      });
    }
  };
```

**Step 2:**

enable  `sharedCookiesEnabled` props and get saved cookies in componentWillMount and make required [webview header cookies formate](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-webview/blob/v10.1.0/docs/Guide.md#managing-cookies) by `jsonCookiesToCookieString` function and stop render webview by `isReady` props utils you get cookies

```
jsonCookiesToCookieString = (json) => {
    let cookiesString = '';
    for (let [key, value] of Object.entries(json)) {
      cookiesString += `${key}=${value.value}; `;
    }
    return cookiesString;
  };
```

```
provideMeSavedCookies = async () => {
    try {
      let value = await AsyncStorage.getItem('savedCookies');
      if (value !== null) {
        return Promise.resolve(JSON.parse(value));
      }
    } catch (error) {
      return {}
    }
  };
```

```
componentWillMount() {
    this.provideMeSavedCookies()
      .then(async (savedCookies) => {
        let cookiesString = this.jsonCookiesToCookieString(savedCookies);
        const PHPSESSID = await AsyncStorage.getItem('PHPSESSID');
        if (PHPSESSID) {
          cookiesString += `PHPSESSID=${PHPSESSID};`;
        }
        this.setState({cookiesString, isReady: true});
      })
      .catch((e) => {
        this.setState({isReady: true});
      });
  }
```

**Step 3:**

pass cookiesString in [Webview Header](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-webview/blob/v10.1.0/docs/Guide.md#managing-cookies) and write render function like this

```
render() {
    const {cookiesString, isReady} = this.state;
    if (!isReady) {
      return null;
    }
    return (
      <SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
        <WebView
          ref={this.myWebView}
          source={{
            uri: `${domain}`,
            headers: {
              Cookie: cookiesString,
            },
          }}
          scalesPageToFit
          useWebKit
          onLoadEnd={this.onLoadEnd}
          onNavigationStateChange={this.onNavigationStateChange}
          sharedCookiesEnabled
          javaScriptEnabled={true}
          domStorageEnabled={true}
          style={styles.WebViewStyle}
        />
      </SafeAreaView>
    );
  }
```

Comment: Hi @Muhammad Numan,
It is already enabled,
But website shows login page always rather then DashBoard.

Comment: can you share website link and webview component in render so I can identify your problem

Comment: Hi, can you share your contact details ?
Cause i need to share you demo login credentials

Comment: Note: This solution does not work with http-only cookie (obviously)

Comment: @KazuyaGosho do you have solution to make it work with http-only?

Comment: @MuhammadNuman I posted a similar question based on Django backend, I tried your solution and couldn't resolve it yet. Please you please check it https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76887056/how-to-keep-django-web-session-active-in-react-native-webview

Comment: @Prabhakaran No. If your usecase is authentiacation, obtain a token on client side, then inject some JavaScript into the rendered WebView like this: https://github.com/react-native-webview/react-native-webview/issues/1548#issuecomment-1260811067

Comment: I completely stopped using webview and shifted to native code